# Text accidentally selected when clicking on navbar link (chrome mobile on Android)

Tags: javascript, html, css, textselection

When I select text on my html page subsequent clicks on the navbar links will select and deselect the text over and over again. This was tested on chrome (latest version) of a Samsung device with the latest version of android. I am attaching a snippet to understand the problem. Please run the snippet on an Android device to verify the question.

```js
function goTo(){}
```

```css
nav {
    padding: 10px 20px 15px 0;
    height: calc(45px + 1vw);
    justify-content: center;
    user-select: none; /* rende testo non selezionabile */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* firefox */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome, Opera and Safari*/
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE, ms-edge */
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: end;
    background-color: #040405;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transition: .3s ease;
    z-index: 1;
}

nav.light {
    background-color: #EDE8DD;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block; /* allinea orizzontalmente i link della navbar */
    padding-left: calc(15px + 1vw); /* padding a sinistra di ogni link della navbar */
}

nav a {
    color: #A2A2A4 !important;
    text-decoration: none; /* elimina elementi decorativi dei link presenti di default */
    position: relative;
    transition: all .3s ease; /* transizione cambio colore onHover e colore sfondo */
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: calc(10px + 0.8vw);
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; /* evita effetto pressione link */
}

nav.light a {
    color: #575758 !important;
}

nav a.active {
    color: #FEFEFE !important;
}

nav.light a.active {
    color: #040405 !important;
}

nav a.active::before { /* rende visibile striscia sotto link attivo */
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #d52d08;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -5px;
    transition: .3s ease;
    pointer-events: none; /* evita bug che rende la striscia cliccabile */
}

@media (hover : hover) {
    nav a:hover::after { /* rende visibile striscia sotto link quando hover (dispositivi che lo permettono) */
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #d52d08;
        border-radius: 20px;
        height: 3px;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        bottom: -5px;
        transition: .3s ease;
        pointer-events: none; /* evita bug che rende la striscia cliccabile */
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Esame di stato</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="home" class="active" onclick="goTo(id)">Home</a></li><!--
            --><li><a id="educazione_civica" onclick="goTo(id)">Educazione civica</a></li><!--
            --><li><a id="pcto" onclick="goTo(id)">Pcto</a><!--
            --><li><a id="materie"  onclick="goTo(id)">Materie</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  <p style="margin-top: 100px;">Select this text and then if you click on the navbar links the text will be selected and deselected by itself</p>
  <p>This only happens on android</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want to deny the ability to select text throughout my page but I want to avoid this behavior.

This is an example of what happens when I click a link on my navbar after selecting the "Etica" text:
[image: This is an example of what happens when I click a link on my navbar after selecting the "Etica" text]